# How to validate that jsonbody doesnt contain extra fields in springboot REST

Tags: spring-boot, rest, validation

How do you validate that jsonbody doesnt contain extra fields in springboot REST controller, Bean validation works on the field but it do not check if extra fields are present.

for example
Model

```java
public class User {

    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
    private String name;
}
```

REST controller

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/user")
public ResponseEntity addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) throws Exception  {

    userService.save(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

how do you validate the indata below

```json
{
    "name": "Tim",
    "not_allowed": "not_allowed"
}
```

This code do not Validate any extra fields, just the field itself

Comment: With what goal? The field is ignored anyway, what do you want to validate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return error on unknown fields in JSON request body of specific controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315022/return-error-on-unknown-fields-in-json-request-body-of-specific-controllers)

Comment: the goal is not  to be able to send malicious code, you should always validate even if it is ignore, you dont want shit coming in